# Angular ui-select multiple and ui-validate

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-select

In my angular app I use the ui-select (angular-ui-select).

Adding the attribute 'ng-required' does not work if the control is multiple options.

I found the option to add ui-validate tag. and seems that The form does not sending until I fill this field.

This is my code

```
<ui-select multiple ui-validate="{required: 'validateToRequired($value)'}" ng-model="newForm.to" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 100%;">
 ........
</ui-select>
```

And the controller

```
      $scope.validateToRequired = function (value) {
        return !_.isEmpty(value);
    }
     $scope.submit = function () {

            if ($scope.New_Form.$valid) {
alert("valid");
    }
    }
```

My problem is how to find the css class that the field is empty and not validate

Like .ng-invalid Css Class

```
  input.ng-invalid {
            background-color: #FA787E;
        }
```

Currently I don't see any css class in the console

[image]
Thanks

Comment: hope ui-validate is attribute not tag. if so change it

Comment: Didn't u check with inspect elements?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution

```
  <div class="m-b-15" ng-class="{'ui-valid':newForm.to.length>0}">
                        <ui-select multiple ui-validate="{required: 'validateToRequired()'}" ng-model="newForm.to" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 100%;">

                        </ui-select>
                    </div>
```

and the css class

```
form {
        &.ng-submitted {
            .ng-invalid {
                border-color: #FA787E;
                background-color: #fcc9c9;
            }

            .ui-select-multiple {
                border-color: #FA787E;
                background-color: #fcc9c9;
            }

            .ui-valid {
                .ui-select-multiple {
                    border-color: #ccd0d4;
                    background-color: #fff;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can add that directly ui-select rather towrapper